# GrpcServer class not found when using distributed TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to test the distributed computing features of TensorFlow with the following simple commands:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> c = tf.constant("Hello, distributed TensorFlow!")
>>> server = tf.GrpcServer.create_local_server()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GrpcServer'
>>>
```

However, as you can see above, it throws an error of indicating that `GrpcServer` can't be found. I've installed TensorFlow into a "Virtualenv" and the MNIST example works fine. How can I test the distributed capability of TensorFlow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `tf.GrpcServer` is only available if you install a [nightly build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation) of TensorFlow, or build from source. It will be included in the next release (version 0.8).